# Parameterizing a Jenkins job with the versions of multiple upstream jobs

Tags: jenkins, continuous-delivery, build-pipeline, go-cd

I need to create a build pipeline which consists of multiple projects that depend on each other. Here is a simplified illustration:

```
SVN A --> build A --\
                    |
SVN B --> build B --|
                    |
SVN C ----------------> build C
```

The pipeline should work so that when a change is committed to the SVN repository of any of the projects, then that project is build automatically. Additionally, after either A or B has been built, it triggers the building of C.

Each build produces binaries with a unique version number ("X.Y.BuildNumber") and C must get as a parameter the version numbers of both A and B, so that C can be built using those versions. C should default to using the latest successful builds of A and B, but it should also be possible to trigger C manually using an older version of A or B (e.g. if we want to deploy an older version of one of the projects).

Creating a pipeline like this can be done out-of-the-box on [Go](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/go-continuous-delivery), but my company considers it too expensive. *(Update 2014-02-27: Go is not open source and free!)* So now I'm trying to find out how to achieve the same thing using Jenkins, but have not yet found a way. I've only found instructions for creating simple linear and diamond shaped pipelines in Jenkins, but not pipelines with multiple independent upstream projects.

Comment: ThoughtWorks just announced that they would be making Go free & open-source. http://www.thoughtworks.com/news/go-continuous-delivery-now-available-as-free-open-source. So may be you can give it a try again.

Comment: Yup. I heard about that too. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to pass the version numbers from upstream jobs to downstream jobs by using the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin). Write the version number to a file in the upstream job, archive it, and then use that plugin to read it in a downstream job. Select the *Upstream build that triggered this project* and *Use “Last successful build” as fallback* options in the plugin configuration.

For more details, see [Interdependent Build Pipelines with Jenkins](http://dev.solita.fi/2013/05/30/jenkins-build-pipelines.html).

Answer (score 0):

We use the [build-pipeline-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) for something similar and what we do is we provide a groovy script that stores runtime build information to be passed on to downstream projects:

A bit verbose, because we include SVN info for downstream builds:

```
import hudson.model.*
def thr = Thread.currentThread()
def build = thr?.executable

def workspace = build.getWorkspace()

def ant = new AntBuilder() 
ant.exec(executable: "svn", outputproperty: "output", dir: workspace){ 
    arg(line: "info") 
}
svnInfo = ant.project.getProperty("output")
print svnInfo 

def pattern = /Last\s+Changed\s+Author:\s+(\w+)/ 
def matcher = (svnInfo =~ pattern)
def user = matcher[0][1]

def langs = new XmlParser().parseText(build.getParent().getWorkspace().child('pom.xml').readToString())
def appVer = langs.properties.release.text()
def artifactId = langs.artifactId.text()

def params = [
new StringParameterValue('PL_SVN_REVISION', build.getEnvVars()['SVN_REVISION']),
new StringParameterValue('PL_BUILD_NUMBER', build.getEnvVars()['BUILD_NUMBER']),
new StringParameterValue('PL_APP_NAME', 'FooApp'),
new StringParameterValue('PL_COMMITTER_NAME',user ),
new StringParameterValue('PL_APP_VERSION',appVer),
new StringParameterValue('PL_ARTIFACT_ID',artifactId) 
]
build.addAction(new ParametersAction(params))
```

Then in the downstream build they should be available like so:

Example 1, *Set Build Name* input:

```
#${BUILD_NUMBER} - ${ENV,var="PL_APP_NAME"} - ${ENV,var="PL_APP_VERSION"} - ${ENV,var="PL_SVN_REVISION"}
```

Example 2, *Invoke Ant* target input:

```
deploy
  -Denvironment=ONT-base
  -DWAR-LOCATION=%war-repo%/%PL_APP_NAME%/%PL_BUILD_NUMBER%-%PL_SVN_REVISION%/
  -DWAR-NAME=%PL_ARTIFACT_ID%-%PL_APP_VERSION%.%PL_BUILD_NUMBER%-%PL_SVN_REVISION%.war
```

---

**Beware however**, when reusing a downstream project in multiple upstream projects, as there is an [outstanding bug with variables not being passed down correctly](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18162).

Comment: This looks useful for an issue I'm having, but it's not really clear what exactly you're doing or why.  Could you clarify your explanation a bit (maybe add some comments to the code)?